# System.Timers.Timer wandering in Azure Worker Role

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, azure, worker

I have an Azure Worker Role with n (currently n = 2) instances. Each of these instances has a System.Timers.Timer on its main thread that executes every 20 seconds, spawning some work processes. When the role instances boot up initially, they synchronize themselves via internal endpoints so that the timers start at the same time (this works).

Over the course of even a day, these two timers with the same interval tend to wander - one will end up starting several seconds before it used to, and the other may go the same direction or, worse, the other.

My run method is basically the following:

```
public override void Run()
{
    while (true) 
    {               
        GC.KeepAlive(this.LogTimer); // make sure garbage collection never touches the timer                                            
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. What might be causing this?
2. Would adding a Thread.Sleep(sleeptimeinMS) call to the while(true){} loop improve
   this by preventing the main thread from being busy all the time (to
   allow the timer thread to be somehow more free to do its duty?)?
3. Is the right answer that I should try to resync the roles to some
   external clock periodically?
4. Any radically different ways to implement this?

Thanks in advance for your time,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A System.Timers.Timer is not 100% accurate, it is limited by the thread scheduling in the OS. It makes good sense that two separate servers each running a Timer, eventually will get out of synch.

Comment: Yes, I had read that there are accuracy limitations of System.Timers.Timer, and I am not (that) surprised by the behavior I'm seeing, but my application does not require 100% accuracy, just keeping 20-second timers within 5 seconds of each other (I should have said this in my original post). Given those expectations, can you suggest any strategies?

Comment: Try synchronizing against the clock after each tick. One tick should be accurate enough to comfortably hit within a 5 second window.

Comment: OK... you're probably right, and I just need to buckle down and write some code that manages the threads of the Timers that avoids unwanted elapse events. Thanks. I'll test and give you credit if (when) this works.